# Save timestamp in a text file after run a function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Whenever the function in codeigniter will run,I want to save the timestamp in a text file. How can I achieve that?

```php
public function updateData(){
      Running this function each time it will save the timestamp in a text file.
}
```

Comment: What are you struggling with? Getting the timestamp? Writing to a file?

Comment: I have the timestamp ! I just want to save it in a text file outside codeigniter, whenever this function will run.

Comment: [Working with Files](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/files.html#) in the documentation has examples of how to create a file and write to it

Answer (score 0):

you can find more info and examples here -> https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_open.asp

```
 public function updateData(){
             # Running this function each time it will save the timestamp in a text file.
             $path2file = "/docs/";
             $fileName = "timestamp.txt";
             $data = time()."".PHP_EOL; // PHP_EOL - new line
             $fp = fopen($path2file.$filename, 'a');
             fwrite($fp, $data);
        }
```